# Como resolver o erro "Function name must be a string"?

Tags: php, mysqli

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Proj_solos\php\login.php:11 Stack trace: #0 {main}
>   thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Proj_solos\php\login.php on line 11

```
<?php include_once './conexao.php';
$erro= array();
 if (isset($_POST['login']) && strlen($_POST['login']) >0 ){
  if (!isset($_SESSION))
      session_start ();

  $_SESSION['login'] = $mysqli ->escape_string($_POST['login']);
  $_SESSION['senha'] = md5(md5($_POST['senha'])); 

  $sql_code = "SELECT senha,login FROM usuario ->' $_SESSION[login]'";
  $sql_query = $mysqli($sql_code) or die ($mysqli->erro);
  $dado= $sql_query -> fetch_assoc();
  $total = $sql_query -> num_rows;

  if($total ==0){
      $erro[] = "Este Usuario não existe.";
  }else{
      if($dado['senha'] == $_SESSION['senha']){
          $_SESSION['login'] = $dado["ID"];

      }else{
          $erro[]= "senha Incorreta!";
      } 
  }
   if (count($erro ==0 || !isset($erro))){
       echo "<script>alert('Login efetuado com Sucesso');location.href='../php/index.php';</script>";
   }
 }
?>
```

Comment: *Error: Function name must be a string in login.php (11)*. Isso é o que tem de errado. Olhe a linha 11 do arquivo `login.php` e me diga o que você fez...

Comment: Não é para dizer o que está errado. Isso percebemos que você não identificou, senão não teria criado a pergunta. É para explicar o que você fez nesta linha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A linha errada claramente é:

```
$sql_query = $mysqli($sql_code) or die ($mysqli->error);
```

> Foi corrigido a mensagem de erro também, de `$mysqli->erro` para `$mysqli->error`.

Vamos considerar que `$mysqli` seja o objeto de conexão com o banco e o mesmo foi criado no arquivo `conexao.php`. Se esta premissa estiver errada, nada no seu código faz sentido. Se estiver certa, na linha supracitada você está passando o valor de `$sql_code` para o objeto `$mysqli`:

```
$mysqli($sql_code)
```

Isto não faz sentido. Para você executar um comando SQL, você precisa invocar o método `query` deste objeto. Partindo do pressuposto que está utilizando a sintaxe OOP do MySQLi, ficaria algo como:

```
$mysqli->query($sql_code)
```

Isso resolveria o erro atual, mas geraria outro, pois o seu comando SQL está errado:

```
SELECT senha,login FROM usuario ->' $_SESSION[login]'
```

Você usou esta sintaxe de flecha que não existe no SQL. Provavelmente o que você queria fazer é:

```
SELECT senha, login FROM usuario WHERE login = '{$_SESSION[login]}'
```

Perceba o uso da cláusula `WHERE`, a identificação da coluna `login` e o uso do operador `=`.

---

A última condição do código também não faz sentido:

```
if (count($erro ==0 || !isset($erro))) { ... }
```

Você está passando o retorno da operação `x || y`, que será do tipo booleano, para a função `count`. Você quer contar os elementos de um booleano? Não. Provavelmente o que você queria fazer é:

```
if ((count($erro) == 0) || !isset($erro)) { ... }
```

Mas que também não há porque fazer. O segundo operando irá verificar a não existência da variável `$erro`, mas ela é definida na linha 2, ou seja, sempre existirá. Portanto, `!isset($erro)` sempre retornará `False`, independente do valor de `$erro`. Para verificar se há alguma mensagem de erro, basta o `count`:

```
if (count($error) == 0) { ... }
```

Comment: obg alterei mais ainda esta dando o erro vou refazer meu codigo porque provavelmente o erro deve estar no conexao.php

Comment: @JeanGuilherme a mensagem de erro te diz exatamente o que está errado, não precisa ficar tentando adivinhar.

Comment: Tem como votar de novo? xD  Explicação excelente !!

Answer (score -2):

`$mysqli` está como variável. Ela deve ser um comando, ou seja, sem o $ (cifrão). Apenas `mysqli`.

Comment: eu tirei do 1 mysqli e da esse novo erro:                                             
 Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Proj_solos\php\login.php:11 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Proj_solos\php\login.php on line 11

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss ,minha aplicaçao e pra fazer cadastro e o login e quando configuro a variavel $sql_query que e pra pegar o valo da $sql_code da esse erro

Comment: Cara, é como o @AndréBail quis dizer, você esta colocando sua variavel dentro da string, tem que concatenar o valor e formar a consulta. Troca usuario ->' $_SESSION[login]' por WHERE usuario = '".$_SESSION[login]."'

Comment: Exatamente como o @MarcosMarques disse, o ponto ( `.` ) serve para concatenar.